# Linking custom objects to a contact

Tags: relationships, app

We recently purchased Salesforce and an app (I am not sure if that is the right term) with custom tabs (might be an custom object). When we enter a customer (contact?), the program is designed so that we then conduct 3 screens with which are contained in the custom tabs/objects. Just one problem... I have to click on the contact page and enter the patient.  Then when I open one of the tabs I have to select the patient. This happens on tab 1, tab 2, and tab3. This is not very efficient. It seems there should be a way to link the pages/tabs/objects (again, I am not sure of the technical name) together so when after I finish entering the customer I can move directly through the other tabs.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Does the page you are looking at show the linked objects?  Let's say you are looking at a Contact, does it display the Account anywhere?  It is probably a link that will take you directly to that account if you want.

Now, lets say you are looking at an Account.  Towards the bottom of the page, is there a list of Contacts?  There should be a link on each of those to take you directly to the contact.

Now, if these things don't exist, you can add them to your 'Page Layout'  There should be a link near the top of the current page called 'Edit Layout'.  You can drag the Account field from the Contact OR if you are on the Account page, you can add the 'Contact' related list.